# System.ObjectDisposedException is thrown after Close is called

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a form to handle login to my app, and I'm trying to make the application exit if the login form is closed without logging in (for example, Alt-F4-ing). To do this I call `Close()` on the main form when `DialogResult.OK` is not returned but get an exception thrown in `Main` by `Application.Run`.

This is for a project I'm working on. Have tried searching for answers and found some saying to call `Application.Exit()` in the main form but that just makes my form reappear.

The main form's constructor:

```
public Menu()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Form login = new Login_Forms.Login();
    Hide();
    if (login.ShowDialog(this) != DialogResult.OK)
        Close();
    else
        Show();
}
```

Main():

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Menu());    // This line throws System.ObjectDisposedException
}
```

The program itself works but the exception thrown here is driving me mad. I'm searching for a way to close the main form properly so that an exception won't be thrown in Main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `Close()` in constructor, before the object is fully created. Move your code to [Form.Load()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: The whole code should be refactored, if the startup of the application is requiring the user to respond to a dialog, why not show that first, why construct the "main form" and let it show this dialog?